# Update on Oracle with join

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I have the Following Statement and need to create an update.

```
Select p.POS_NR, p1.VON_POS_NR 
FROM table1 p. inner join table2 p1 
ON p.Bestell_NR = p1.Vorgangs_NR 
and p.Bestell_pos = p1.Vorgangs_pos 
where NOT (p.POS_NR = p1.Von_Pos_NR)
```

Now I want to equal p.POS_NR and p1.Von_POS_NR, but I don't know how to create the update

I  hope someone can help me

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result.[ask] and [mcve] can be useful to improve your question

Comment: @TomNeumann Edit the question with proper query (minimal but complete in logic) so that proper solutions can be given

Comment: Please, have a look at the link I gave you to post a better question. Also, as said, when you have some more useful content, please edit the question accordingly, instead of adding comments. Also, have you tried searching? I guess that a simple search for something like "Oracle update join" will give useful results

Comment: What  is/are the name of the primary key fields on TABLE1?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a MERGE statement. I'll assume that TABLE1 has a primary key field named KEY_FIELD - you can substitute as necessary:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 t1
  USING (SELECT p.KEY_FIELD, p.POS_NR, p1.VON_POS_NR 
           FROM TABLE1 p
           INNER JOIN TABLE2 p1 
             ON p.BESTELL_NR = p1.VORGANGS_NR and
                p.BESTELL_POS = p1.VORGANGS_POS 
           WHERE NOT (p.POS_NR = p1.VON_POS_NR) d
    ON (d.KEY_FIELD = t1.KEY_FIELD)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
      SET t1.POS_NR = d.VON_POS_NR;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll try it. But i'll need to merge in table2 but this should work